# multi line headers with web2py's SQLFORM.grid

Tags: python, html, web2py

What is the best way to make the headers for SQLFORM.grid.  I've tried inserting a '\n' in the field header and passing a list, but neither worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to insert a `<br />`, which you can do as follows:

Using HTML helpers:

```
CAT('Line 1', BR(), 'Line 2')
```

or wrapping raw HTML in an `XML()` object (to prevent escaping when serialized in the view):

```
XML('Line 1<br />Line 2')
```

Note, instead of using the "headers" argument to `SQLFORM.grid`, you can directly specify the label to be used for a given database table field:

```
db.define_table('mytable',
    Field('myfield', label=CAT('My', BR(), 'Label')))
```

or after the table has already been defined:

```
db.mytable.myfield.label = CAT('My', BR(), 'Label')
```

When you define a label for the field, it will be used in all SQLFORMs, SQLTABLEs, and SQLFORM.grids, so you only have to define it once.